# sql server express: no connection from pool available on developer machine with a single user

Tags: sql-server, connection, sql-server-express, connection-pooling

I'm currently porting a DB-backed web application from MS Access to SQL Server (Express, for the time being). While expecting improved availability of the DB, I'm getting timeouts when connecting, error message "couldn't get connection from pool in time" (sorry original error message is in German so I'm only paraphrasing it).

This is happening while I'm the only user on the machine, only testing the code. Even taking into account that I have aborted a few executions and may have some connections lying around, I can't imagine I've reached the pool size of 100 connections. Also, I can still run queries from the management studio. How do I go about finding out what's wrong with the database? Also, I don't see information about the pool status in the activity monitor... any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're leaving connections open somewhere. It's best if every use of a database connection is wrapped in a using statement, so that you're guaranteed that they're closed/disposed when they're no longer being used.

Not knowing what data access layer you're using, I can't suggest specific code.

Comment: I guess I underestimated the importance of closing and disposing connections.  I went through all the code and inserted using statements. Turns out the error's gone now. 

Maybe a follow-up question: For some data binding code, I used to store a connection in an instance variable, then use that connection from the event handler and close the connection after data binding. To be on the safe side, I now use a using... construct everywhere, i.e. sometimes when I display 50 items, I open and close/dispose the connection 50 times. How expensive is this operation really in ASP.NET/MSSQL?

Comment: @Nicolas - assuming you've not changed any settings, ADO.NET will perform "connection pooling" - where the actual network connection to SQL Server is kept open and reused to service each `SqlConnection` object - provided that these objects are closed promptly before the next one is opened. Otherwise, 2 or 3 "physical" connections may be required - but it will still not be anywhere near the number of `SqlConnection` objects that you open and close.